Most efficient way to sort an object based on value with a special rule
I have a situation where I want to create an array based on values (numbers) in an object like so. However, the catch is that if there is ever multiple keys with the same value, then I want the secondary rule to be to sort the array based on alphabetical order. For example:


const object1 = {
  'Andy': 10,
  "loves": 10,
  "to": 0,
  "Have": 2,
  "tacos": 15,
  "when": 10,
  "he": 0,
  "is": 7,
  "sad": 4
};

const result = []

//Expected Result: ["he", "to", , "Have", "sad", "is", 'Andy', "loves", "when":, "tacos"]



So in this case there are multiple values with 0, but "he" would come before "to" in the array because of the secondary rule of prioriting alphabetical order.
I know that I should be able to convert the object into an array and then sort it based on value, but I cant figure out how to enact the secondary alphabetical rule. Can anyone guide me as to what might be the most optimal way to accomplish this?

Is your expected result supposed to be an array of objects?

There are no the type ["string":0] in js.

Does this answer your question? How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?

@Unmitigated I corrected the expected result which is an array of strings

@random_narwhal I've updated my answer to match your expected output.

You can use a comparator that calls String#localeCompare on the keys to determine the sorting order when the values are equal.


const object1 = {
  'Andy': 10,
  "loves": 10,
  "to": 0,
  "Have": 2,
  "tacos": 15,
  "when": 10,
  "he": 0,
  "is": 7,
  "sad": 4
};
const res = Object.keys(object1).sort((k1, k2) => 
              object1[k1] - object1[k2] || k1.localeCompare(k2));
console.log(res);




Interesting. I guess the question then becomes why that method is needed. Shouldnt you be able to do this instead. Why doesn't k1 < k2 work?
const res = Object.keys(object1).sort((k1, k2) =>
object1[k1] - object1[k2] || k1 < k2

@random_narwhal k1 < k2 is not a valid comparator. Comparators MUST return negative for less than, 0 for equal, and positive for greater. k1 < k2 has never satisfied that and has never been valid; returning that in a sort method is always a mistake.

You can use Object.entries() and Array#map() as follows:


const 
    input = { "Andy": 10, "loves": 10, "to": 0, "Have": 2, "tacos": 15, "when": 10, "he": 0, "is": 7, "sad": 4 },

    output = Object.entries(input).sort(
        ([k1,v1], [k2,v2]) => v1 - v2 || k1.localeCompare(k2)
    )
    .map(([k,v]) => k);
    
console.log(output);



